# Windows Phone 7 Tab Pages (page cycle)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I know.. I know, it's only a few hours old.

But how the hell do you get the little page tabbing/cycle (forgot what the official name is) on the top of the page under the app title.

MIX Keynotes made it look like it was a control (or at least what I saw, was @ work).

Anyone who made MIX or knows how they are doing this, it'd be cool to get an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: The guy running the demo of the photo-browsing application called them "menu items" - perhaps it's a MainMenu control or something similar?

Comment: Nope, no menu control exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called Pivots but don't see them available

Comment: After looking, it appears they didn't make the CTP. Thanks for the real name though.

Comment: Hopefully the "Pivot" control make the RTM release of the tools for Windows Phone 7 - confusing as there is a Pivot control for Silverlight which is different, similar to the Bing visual search system and nothing like the "Pivot" control demonstrated for WP7.

Answer (score 0):

Someone implemented it as a control:

It is available at [codeplex](http://phone.codeplex.com/)